# vb.net subroutine not updating module level variable until exit sub

Tags: vb.net, thread-safety, visual-studio-2017

I have come to learn that a module level variable's value will not be altered until a sub routine that changed it exits.

```
        StopBackgroundWorker1 = True
    Thread.Sleep(1500)

    If BackgroundWorker1Complete = False Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

in this example, I added a long delay for testing. I'm simply trying to stop and start a background worker safely with vb 2017 new background worker class.

The example above with "StopBackgroundWorker1 = True", I was hoping to stop the worker at a safe place and then continue within that sub with other code.

But what is happening is that the "StopBackgroundWorker1 = True" is not being set "True" until the sub exits.

There must be another way to do what I am trying to do, please help

Ok here is a complete example,

```
    Imports System.ComponentModel
    Imports System.Threading



  Public Class Form1


Private flag As Boolean = False
Dim Completed As Boolean = False


Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


    flag = True

    'Do
    '  do loop never see's a true flag
    'Loop Until Completed

    Thread.Sleep(500)

    If Completed = True Then
        Label1.BackColor = Color.Red
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork

    Do
        Thread.Sleep(25)
    Loop Until flag


End Sub


Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As 
RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    Completed = True
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
Button2.Click
    Label1.Text = flag.ToString
End Sub
 End Class
```

Now the concept is if you hit button1 and wait for background worker to complete, it should turn lable1 red. but it doesn't. The do loop looking for a true flag will spin forever locking the form up.

I have determined with this example that the flag is not set to true until you exit the sub. Hit Button1 again and lable1 turns red.

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: In which level did you declare the variable `StopBackgroundWorker1`?

Comment: You're under a number of misconceptions. First, VB 2017 doesn;t have a new `BackgroundWorker` class. `BackgroundWorker` has been available to all .NET languages since .NET 2.0, which coincided with the release of VB 2005.

Comment: Secondly, you don't start and stop a `BackgroundWorker`. You call the `RunWorkerAsync` method and the `BackgroundWorker` simply raises an event. That event is handled by your form and the `DoWork` event handler is part of the form, not the `BackgroundWorker`.

Comment: Finally, a variable's value changes the moment you set it. How could it be any other way? There is no buffer for a variable that holds potential values. A variable is a memory location and when you assign a value to that location, that's it's value.

Comment: You really need to show us ALL the relevant code for us to be able to work out what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, the background worker is different in dot.net 4.7 according to the documentation. "jmcilhinney" in the answers has provided an example to work with, and I will clarify my problem with that example.

Comment: As for the level of the variable, it is stated in the question "module level". If you don't understand that read the beginning of vb programming!

Comment: "Finally, a variable's value changes the moment you set it." This is what I am challenging. I state that it does not change until the exit sub happens.

Comment: I don't see where there is any indication that the `BackgroundWorker` class has changed in .NET 4.7. Can you please direct me to such a change if it exists? As for your challenge, you're still wrong. I'll edit my answer and explain why. This is a perfect demonstration of why you need to provide ALL the relevant information upfront though. The issue is obvious now that we have all the relevant code.

Comment: As for my statement that the backgroundworker was new, I should have said changed such as suspend and resume are now depreciated.

Comment: As for showing you all relevant information that would be "Stupid" as my project has many classes and pages and pages of code! " jmcilhinney" helped by providing some sort of experiment on the core issue.

Comment: If I am unable to stop the BackgroundWorker at a safe point and MS documentation states that the "event handler" was added to help with stopping a thread at a safe point "Depending on the code used" and restart the thread without user intervention then the Backgroundworker is useless for my project.

Comment: Many thanks to " jmcilhinney" who once properly understood the problem helped explain a concept in vb that I did not fully realize and in his comments he does not fully realize is that event handlers mostly run on a main thread while some others are not. Many thanks to " jmcilhinney"

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your question per se but I want to post a large code snippet so I'll post it as an answer.  It demonstrates that what you think is the problem is not the problem, i.e. that a field's value changes as soon as you change it, even if that change is made from a `BackgroundWorker.DoWork` event handler.

Create a new Windows Forms application project, add a `Button`, a `Label` and a `BackgroundWorker` to your form and then paste in this code over the default code of the form:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Form1

    Private flag As Boolean

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        BackgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = True
        BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Label1.Text = flag.ToString()
    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
        Thread.Sleep(5000)

        flag = True
        BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0)

        Thread.Sleep(5000)
    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
        Label1.BackColor = Color.Green
    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
        Label1.BackColor = Color.Red
    End Sub

End Class
```

Run the project and, when the form appears, start clicking the `Button` at a pace of a few times per second.  You'll see that the value of the `flag` field, as displayed on the `Label`, changes from `False` to `True` as soon as the code to set it is executed in the `DoWork` event handler.  The `Label` will turn green when that happens, so it's easy to spot.  You'll know that it didn't wait until the `DoWork` event handler completes because the `Label` will turn red at that point.

EDIT: Now that you have provided all the relevant information, the issue is obvious. As I have already said, the moment you set a variable, that is the value of that variable.  There's no waiting because there cannot be any waiting because there's nowhere to store a temporary value for the variable.

The reason that it looks otherwise is that your test code is faulty.  If you use the debugger then you will see how.  When you use a `BackgroundWorker`, the `DoWork` event handler is executed on a secondary thread but the `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler is executed on the UI thread.  That means that your `DoWork` event handler can execute at the same time as your `Click` event handler for `Button1` because they are on different threads, but the `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler cannot run at the same time, so it has to wait until the `Click` event handler completes before it can be executed.  That means that the code to set the `Completed` field doesn't get executed until the `Click` event handler completes.  It's not that the field value doesn't change when it's set but rather that it doesn't actually get set.  If you place breakpoints on the two lines that access that `Completed` field then you'll see that.

The mistake you're making is trying to do something in that `Click` event handler after the `DoWork` event handler completes.  That's wrong.  That's exactly what the `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler is for.  That's where you do UI work after the background work completes.

Also, you can get rid of that `flag` variable.  Cancellation functionality is built into the `BackgroundWorker` class.  Look at the `CancelAsync` method and the `CancellationPending` property.

Comment: Thank you for example! I will run the example and then add a thread.sleep after "Label1.Text = flag.ToString()" and I should get the same results I see with my project. it is my intention in my project to wait for the "RunWorkerCompleted" flag and continue with other work in the same sub routine.

Comment: Changing my first comment, you are changing the flag inside the BackgroundWorker1 thread. What I'm doing is the complete opposite. changing the variable from a button and trying to read it from inside the thread. Will change your example to demonstrate.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, after this experiment I was coming to the conclusion that the event handler must wait for the main thread. I have already tried "CancelAsync" with the same results. You explained the problem very well and thanks for that.

Comment: I have used similar code elsewhere like on the serial port where documentation states that the event handler is fired on a separate thread. So that will be my next experiment shifting the event handler or my wait for event.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to "jmcilhinney" for his insights! I have figured out the code I was looking for!

This code allows me to stop and start a background thread safely by allowing the background thread to finish completely before restarting.

During the time that the background thread is stopped, user actions can perform operations without the worry of cross-threading or with thread.abort garbled code conditions.

Finally, stress-free threading!

I wish I could find the doc on MSDN that I read that stated the await async method was far superior to task.run but that's another argument.

This may not be the best code in the world but it works!

And in light of trying to rewrite all code in my project with async and await I'll stick with this!

```
  Public Class Form1


Private flag As Boolean = False
Dim Completed As Boolean = False


Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    flag = True

    Await Task.Run(Sub()
                       Do
                       Loop Until Completed
                   End Sub)

    If Completed = True Then
        Label1.BackColor = Color.Red
    End If

    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()

End Sub


Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork

    Do
        Thread.Sleep(250)
    Loop Until flag


End Sub


Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As 
RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    Completed = True
End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

For all of the academics out there this code is more appropriate.

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Threading


Public Class Form1

Private Completed As Boolean = False


Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    BackgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
Button1.Click

    BackgroundWorker1.CancelAsync()

    Await Task.Run(Sub()
                       Do
                       Loop Until Completed
                   End Sub)

    If Completed = True Then
        Label1.BackColor = Color.Red
    End If

    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()

End Sub


Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork

    Do
        Thread.Sleep(250)
    Loop Until BackgroundWorker1.CancellationPending


End Sub


Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    Completed = True
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I have been researching this for weeks. How to start, stop, restart a background thread with absolute safety. Finally, here it is!

Comment: Silly me for got to set "completed" to false before restarting thread!